# Why does this bash file stop my tomcat if the session closes?

Tags: bash, tomcat

The following bash script starts an Apache Tomcat and tails the log file to the screen:

```
#!/bin/bash
~/tomcats/TC1_8083/bin/startup.sh
tail -f ~/tomcats/TC1_8083/logs/catalina.out
```

If I CTRL-C the tail, the bash script ends and the Tomcat continues to run correctly even if I log off. However if my session dies (for example through a network disconnect) WHILST the tail is still running then the Tomcat stops too. If I had CTRL-C'ed the tail, then the Tomcat will not stop until I choose to kill it.

I'm not interested in keeping the tail alive on a network disconnect, I just want the Tomcat to continue running regardless.

I can't understand this behaviour. Can someone please explain it? Also how could I change the script so that the Tomcat would continue to run even if the network became disconnected?

Comment: When the shell dies (e.g. at logout) it **may** send a signal to its children, allowing them to gracefully stop. This was veryt desired in ye old times when modem lines often dropped. These days it is configurable. See [`shopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) `huponexit`

Answer (score 0):

When you call a script from another script, it runs in the background (Otherwise you'd have two scripts simultaneously running in the foreground, both trying to output to the screen)

When you hit Ctrl-C you are sending a Interrupt signal to your script (Not just tail), but the tomcat script continues to run in the background as it is a separate script.

When your session dies, all running scripts are terminated, including those running in the background.

If you want scripts to continue running when you disconnect from the network (intentionally or otherwise) I recommend tmux or screen.

Comment: I don't need the tail to persist if the session dies so don't need tmux or screen. However if I run startup.sh from the command line, startup.sh runs and continues to run even if I log off or disconnect. So why exactly does it stop if my script dies? You said: "When your session dies, all running scripts are terminated, including those running in the background." Do you actually mean "When your session dies, all running scripts are terminated, including those scripts spawned from the running scripts" ? If so how could I modify my script to keep startup.sh alive. Adding an ampersand didn't work